# removing colors below lines from morris area charts

Tags: javascript, morris.js

I need to remove colors below lines in morris area charts, how do I do that?

Below is the code I am using

```
Morris.Area({
  element: 'area-example',
  data: [
    { y: '2006', a: 100, b: 90 },
    { y: '2007', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2008', a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { y: '2009', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2010', a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { y: '2011', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2012', a: 100, b: 90 }
  ],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
  labels: ['Series A', 'Series B'],
  fillOpacity: 0.0,
  lineColors: ['#00acac' , '#348fe2'],


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to show colors below lines then use Line chart,it's simpler

```
Morris.Line({
  element: 'area-example',
  data: [
    { y: '2006', a: 100, b: 90 },
    { y: '2007', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2008', a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { y: '2009', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2010', a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { y: '2011', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2012', a: 100, b: 90 }
  ],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
  labels: ['Series A', 'Series B']

});
```

Or you can use something like this, adding fill Opacity (fillOpacity) on fill area below the lines

```js
Morris.Area({
  element: 'chart',
  data: [
    { y: '2015-01', a: 1, b: 2 },
    { y: '2015-02', a: 2,  b: 3 },
    { y: '2015-03', a: 2,  b: 2 },
    { y: '2015-04', a: 1,  b: 4 },
    { y: '2015-05', a: 2,  b: 5 },
    { y: '2015-06', a: 3,  b: 3 },
    { y: '2015-07', a: 1, b: 2 }
  ],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
  labels: ['Value A', 'Value B'],
  fillOpacity: 0.8,
  hideHover: 'auto',
  resize: true,
  pointFillColors: ['#fff'],
  pointStrokeColors: ['black'],
  lineColors: ['#f1a340', '#998ec3'],
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.oesmith.co.uk/morris-0.5.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.oesmith.co.uk/morris-0.5.1.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

Hope it helps, enjoy :)